# Volume change event - listen when volume stopped changing

Tags: c#, listener, volume

My server is controlling windows volume using a third party library.
When the server gets a message from the client telling it to change volume it's doing what it need to with no issues. However, I want to inform back to the client whenever the volume was changed locally on the computer.

This library I'm using (https://workspaces.codeproject.com/ray-m/vista-core-audio-api-master-volume-control/article), has an event to notify volume changes.

Problem is, it inform on every small volume change step and therefor the delegate is being called numerous times when a user changes volume. Example:

If current volume is -23db and the user turns up the volume to a -13db then the delegate will be called 10 times!

How can I listen for when the user started changing volume and then when it ended the action?

This way I'll be able to send to the client the update through the delegate only once.

Code tried:

```
void AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification(AudioVolumeNotificationData data)
{

    VolumeTimer.Interval = 300;
    VolumeTimer.Stop();
    VolumeTimer.Start();

}

private void VolumeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    VolumeTimer.Stop();

    lock (_lock)
    {
        ++_volumeCalledCounter;

        if (_volumeCalledCounter <= 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fired");
            _volumeCalledCounter = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Start/restart a Timer each time. When it Ticks the volume changes are done. Test to find a good Interval, 500ms could work.

Comment: Can you give me some example? As far as I see, a timer will fire event automatically on specified intervals. I want to "absorb" some amount of events and only then fire one event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a `Timer` can fire repeatedly. Therefore you should `Stop` and `Start` it each time you get a volumeChange notification. While these come in faster than the `Timer.Interval` nothing else will happen. Once they stop coming, the `Timer.Tick` will finally fire. Here you stop the `Timer` one last time and fire your own event.

Using a `Timer VolumeTimer` and the original sources:

```
defaultDevice.AudioEndpointVolume.OnVolumeNotification += new 
    AudioEndpointVolumeNotificationDelegate(
       AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification);


void AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification(AudioVolumeNotificationData data)
{
   VolumeTimer.Interval = 100;  // ms, test to gauge!
   VolumeTimer.Stop();
   VolumeTimer.Start();
}

private void VolumeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   VolumeTimer.Stop();
   // whatever you want to do, when the volume no longer changes:
   yourEvent();         
}
```

**Edit:**

The above code should solve the original question.

However, if the user changes the volume slowly but for a prolonged time, your event won't fire all this time. If you want to enforce an UI update a little extra code will do that, using a second `Timer VolumeUiTimer` :

```
void AudioEndpointVolume_OnVolumeNotification(AudioVolumeNotificationData data)
{
   VolumeTimer.Interval = 100;  // ms, test to gauge!
   VolumeTimer.Stop();
   VolumeTimer.Start();
   if (!VolumeUiTimer.Enabled) 
      { VolumeUiTimer.Interval = 500; VolumeUiTimer.Start();
}

private void VolumeTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  // no more changes: all timers stop, update UI
   VolumeTimer.Stop();
   VolumeUiTimer.Stop();
   // whatever you want to do, when the volume no longer changes:
   yourEvent();         
}

private void VolumeUiTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //restart timer1, stop timer2, update UI 
   VolumeTimer.Stop();
   VolumeTimer.Start();
   VolumeUiTimer.Stop();
   // whatever you want to do, when the volume no longer changes:
   yourEvent();         
}
```

I set the `Intervals` here just for demonstration; they could be moved to after `InitializeComponent()` or simply into the designer.

**Aside** on multiple `Timers`: There was a time when the number of `Timers` an application could create was limited to, I think 16. That is long gone and there is no problem creating a second `Timer`.

Comment: Thank u that looks interesting, I'll test it soon.

Comment: @Yosi199: See my expanded answer!

Comment: I've implemented your example (no need for the second timer since I want to fire event only when stopped changing volume, at least for now)

But for some reason I still get the event fired twice no matter what! I will post my code implementation in my post

Comment: Maybe it was a bug or something because it works good now - firing only one event at a time

Comment: Ha, thanks for letting me know!! I was puzzling over this - to test I have hooked into the MouseMove not knowing that this event is unexpectedly tricky and keeps firing for no (obvious) reason even without moving the mouse, which kept me scratching my head.. ;-)